# Super User's new Twitter name

Tags: discussion, twitter

As you may know, there is a Twitter account that automatically tweets out questions from superuser.com. Previously, this account was using @stacksuper_user for two reasons:

1. Twitter does not allow anyone to use the account name @superuser, for whatever reason
2. Someone else had reserved @super_user

The account @super_user has since been abandoned, and we were able to persuade Twitter to let us claim it.

As of today, the official Twitter feed for this site lives at [@super_user](https://twitter.com/super_user).

Anyone who previously followed the old account is automatically following the new one; no change needed on your end.

The reason I'm announcing this is because if you want to @-mention the account, you will need to use @super_user rather than the old @stacksuper_user name. I think the latter is more intuitive and should also be a bit more discoverable for people who may be browsing/searching twitter wondering if Super User is on there.

Comment: #omg #bestnewsever

Comment: Like seriously? Wow!

Comment: Nice. But... why would anyone @-mention an automated newsfeed of average questions?

Comment: @DanielBeck People doing "old style" retweets (typing "RT @super_user...") is the most logical case. Sometimes people @-mention accounts as a way of helping them gain exposure - in a #ff (Follow Friday) kind of way.